# Change Button class in angular on some condition when html loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two state in angular one state is for accept terms and another is to show user who is not accept terms. Accept terms state dynamically populate n-numbers of users and in front of their name they have two buttons which labeled as 'I Agree' and 'I do not Agree'. By default Buttons are in default class but when users click button like 'I Agree' then its class change(like button color is green) same thing happens with 'I do not agree' button(color change to red). After clicking buttons user submit request then it goes to another html page that shows who is accept and reject. In this page there is back button which goes to back previous state.

My problem is that when user goes back to previous state I have to change button class according to user's choice on loading state.

On click event it is working fine for this I write this code in html:

```
<div class="mar-right10">
  <md-button class="md-raised md-default" id="agree{{$index}}" 
    ng-class="userBaseExtend.acceptedTermsAndCondition === 'true' ? 'md-primary' : 'md-default'" 
    role="button" ng-click="vm.agree(userBaseExtend)">
    I Agree
  </md-button>
</div>
<div flex="" flex-xs="">
  <md-button class="md-raised md-default" id="disagree{{$index}}" 
  ng-class="userBaseExtend.acceptedTermsAndCondition === 'false' ? 'md-warn' : 'md-default'" 
  role="button" ng-click="vm.disagree(userBaseExtend)">
    I Do Not Agree
  </md-button>
</div>
```

for loading back to previous state I write this class but its not work in my controller :

```
if (vm.rejTermsAndCondition) {
  for (var i = 0; i < vm.userBaseExtends.length; i++) {
    if (vm.userBaseExtends[i].acceptedTermsAndCondition) {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#agree' + i)).attr('ng-class', 'md-primary');
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#agree' + i)).removeAttr('ng-class', 'md-default');
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#disagree' + i)).attr('ng-class', 'md-default');
    } else {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#agree' + i)).addClass('md-default');
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#disagree' + i)).removeClass('md-default').addClass('md-warn');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please format the code